# Classes don't seem to load while running tests

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, phpunit, autoload

I'm new to Laravel and PhpUnit and I'm trying to run some tests located in the \App\Tests\Unit folder on customs classes located in the \App\Musibits directory.

I get the following when I run phpunit in the \App\Tests\Unit directory:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Tonality' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\musibits\app\tests\TonalityTest.php on line 8
```

Tonality.php contains my class and is in the \App\Musibits directory

I read numerous posts about autoloading and bootstrap, but I can't seem to make it work :-(

Here is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/musibits",
            "app/tests"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

There is three autoload files included with Laravel, one for composer, one for phpunit and one for Laravel, I didn't change any.

Any cues would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

to generate new class map

Comment: ...lost so much time on this. Thanks a lot! I can't vote you as an answer, yet. Have a nice day!